# Prove inequality holds for Single variable differentiable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

I saw this question in another post and I proved it differently than the others who answered.  I was wondering if my proof works.

**Problem**

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable, that $f(0)=1$, and that $|f'(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $|f(x)| \leq |x|+1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

**My Proof**

Assume the conclusion didn't follow from the hypotheses, namely that $\exists x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)|>|x|+1$.  We can show this for $x=0$.  Then we get $|f(0)|>1 \Longrightarrow 1>1$, contradiction.

---

And here's where I found the question  [Practice problem from Mean Value Theorem in Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25798/practice-problem-from-mean-value-theorem-in-real-analysis?rq=1)

Comment: What do you mean by "we can show this for $x=0$"? Also, where did you use that $f$ is differentiable with $|f'|\leq 1$?

Comment: Well I'm proceeding by contradiction, so I'm assuming the conclusion fails in some case, namely the case where $x=0$.  And I didn't see the need to use those conditions since the contradiction followed immediately, if I did the proof correctly

Comment: If you proceed by contradiction, you just get that the conclusion fails for **some** $x$. You cannot just assume that $x=0$. Also, since the claim is false without the assumption on the derivative, your proof is necessarily wrong if you nowhere use that assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you say that $x=0$ is the point where $|f(0)|>|0|+1$?

We assume that there exists a point, $x_0$ such that $|f(x_0)|>|x_0|+1$, then we look at $$\frac{f(x_0)-f(0)}{x_0-0}$$ and you use this to prove that there is a point where $|f'(x)|>1$.

You **can't** just say "$x_0=0$", because the negative of all is exists, so it may be $0$, but it is also may be $10,5.4,777,\pi$ and so on.

Comment: So when proving a contradiction you negate the conclusion and show that the negated conclusion, with the given hypothesis, lead to a contradiction.  But I began by negating the conclusion, $|f(x)|>|x|+1$, then I used the conditions to find a contradiction, namely the condition that $f(0)=1$.

Comment: @johnfowles what you did is assuming that a specific value of $x_0$  satisfy the negative of $|f(x)| \leq |x|+1$, but you need to show that if **a** value, not specific one, some arbitrary $x_0$, satisfy the negative of $|f(x)| \leq |x|+1$ then you have contradiction

Comment: ok, this makes sense